# Handle two signals the same way in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, signals, reactive-cocoa, frp, reactive-cocoa-3

Let's say I have two signals

```
textField1Signal
|> map { value in
    return value.lowercaseString
}
|> on (
    next: { value in
         println("textField1 changed to \(value)");
    }
)


textField2Signal
|> map { value in
    return value.lowercaseString
}
|> on (
    next: { value in
        println("textField2 changed to \(value)");
    }
)
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
(textField1Signal & textField2Signal)
|> map { value in
    return value.lowercaseString
}
|> on (
    next: { value in
         println("one of the textFields changed to \(value)");
    }
)
```

The point is I have several Signals and I want to handle all of them the same way. `combineLatest:` does not work in this case because first of all it is not fired when only one of the signals fires and second of all I would get the values from both textfields and wouldn't know which one actually caused the invocation.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for `merge` operator

Comment: Could you provide an example for that?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be `merge` operator in latest RAC - you need to first create `SignalProducer` of `SignalProducers` and then merge them view `flatten(,Merge)` operator. I'm not behind my mac today - so cant write tested answer, but here are some pointers on how to do it: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1929

Answer (score 0):

With Jakub Vanos help I was able to find the following solution

```
SignalProducer<SignalProducer<String, NSError>, NSError>(values: [textField1Signal, textField2Signal])
|> flatten(.Merge)
|> map { value in
    return value.lowercaseString
}
|> on (
    next: { value in
        println("one of the textFields changed to \(value)");
    }
)
```